# How to convert byte[] to Object and vice versa in Groovy

Tags: arrays, object, groovy, byte

I am trying to convert a byte[] to an Object using **Groovy**. My actual Groovy Class that is represented by the byte array implements the Serializable interface and is stored in a separate Groovy class file. However I always get a `ClassNotFoundException` of this class when trying to call my `toObject` function. My code is written in Java and works when using Java but not when using Groovy.

```
private static byte[] toByteArray(Object obj) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        bos.close();
        bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bytes;
}


private static Object toObject(byte[] bytes) {
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        obj = ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); // ClassNotFoundException
    }
    return obj;
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Edit: A class that would be used in this context where the ClassNotFoundException would occur is something like this:

```
public class MyItem implements Serializable {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -615551050422222952L;

public String text


MyItem() {
    this.text = ""
}
}
```

Then testing the whole thing:

```
    void test() {
        MyItem item1 = new MyItem ()
        item1.text = "bla"

        byte[] bytes = toByteArray(item1) // works

        Object o = toObject(bytes) // ClassNotFoundException: MyItem

        MyItem item2 = (MyItem) o

        System.out.print(item.text + " <--> " + item2.text)
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say it's stored in a separate Groovy class file, do you mean an actual .class file compiled by groovyc, or just a separate .groovy file? Your example works as written for me, but only if I compile the source file that defines the Serializable class.

Comment: This is a bit confusing to me.  What class is the target of the ClassNotFoundException?  Is that class compiled?  Is it on the classpath?

Comment: @JustinPiper In a separate .groovy file

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Added some sample code. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess (and this is what @JustinPiper suggested as well) is that you are not compiling your groovy class before referencing it.  You must compile your groovy class using groovyc and make sure that the compiled class file is placed on the classpath (probably in the same file as the java test class).

Comment: For some reason I don't have the problem any longer. I did not change anything that would be related to those classes but now it runs without the exception.... I use IntelliJ so I thought compiling the class would be taken care of when performing a Rebuild. However I can only guess that my problem was related to that. So for anyone having the same problem, try to compile the .groovy class separately before building and starting the rest. In IntelliJ simply right click on the file and press "Compile 'MyItem.groovy'"

Comment: In Eclipse, groovy files will be automatically compiled if they are in a source folder.  There is no way to compile groovy files separately from the rest of the project.

Comment: Since I had the issue AGAIN without knowing why and the separate compiling didn't work either, I ran the grails command `clean` and `clean-proxy`, rebuilt the whole project and now it works again.

Comment: I'm not sure what your project structure is or how this class is loaded, or even when you get this problem. I didn't even know this was a grails project (that changes things). Grails will compile the groovy to the target folder, while Eclipse will compile the groovy to target-eclipse. in general, since Eclipse uses incremental compilation, target-eclipse will *always* be up to date.  however, since grails only compiles when it needs to, the target folder may be out of date.  So, if you are using some funky loading of classes, you may be loading from the wrong output folder. (Just a thought.)